# UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile + Authentication/Authorization Failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, paypal

I am try to make a request `UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile` in Paypal using `HttpWebRequest` in

MVC webapplication. But a problem occurred while processing this request.

Please see my below result.

> TIMESTAMP=2015-08-19T12:07:38Z&CORRELATIONID=c803523ed08bf&ACK=Failure&VERSION=0.000000&BUILD=000000&L_ERRORCODE0=10002&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Authentication/Authorization Failed&L_LONGMESSAGE0=You do not have permissions to make this API call&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp");

        request.Method = "POST";

        string formContent =
                "&METHOD=UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile" +
                "&PROFILEID=" + HttpContext.Current.Session["profileid"] +
                "&AMT=" + amt +
                "&CURRENCYCODE=" + currencycode +
                "&ACCT" + acct +
                "&FIRSTNAME=" + firstname +
                "&LASTNAME=" + lastname +
                "&STREET=" + street +
                "&CITY=" + city +
                "&STATE=" + state +
                "&COUNTRYCODE=" + countrycode +
                "&ZIP=" + zip;

        byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formContent);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        System.IO.Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(dataStream);

        string responseFromServer = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(reader.ReadToEnd());

        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
```

I am already made `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile` command successfully.

Comment: Was the profile created with the same API credentials that you're using to update it?

Comment: But there is no parameter in this method for USER, PWD, SIGNATURE

Comment: I was under the impression that the library you're working with must be appending the API credentials to the formContent string before it's sent.  If that's not true, then as @Ragesh Puthiyedath points out you need to add them.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply. I  am a newbi in Paypal. i missed this in my code.